# How do I split parts of a dataframe by a character?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of input:

```
[["October", "Steve", "Apples"],
 ["November", "Joe", "Oranges"],
 ["December", "James", "Apples/Oranges"]
]
```

I would like to split James' two occurrences in to separate events as designated by the presence of a '/' in the string. Output would be:

```
[["October", "Steve", "Apples"],
 ["November", "Joe", "Oranges"],
 ["December", "James", "Apples"],
 ["December", "James", "Oranges"]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
          A      B               C
0   October  Steve          Apples
1  November    Joe         Oranges
2  December  James  Apples/Oranges
```

You could [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the third column on the `'/'` and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the result. This will yield one row per item:

```
df2 = (df.assign(C=df['C'].str.split('/'))
         .explode('C')
       )
```

output:

```
          A      B        C
0   October  Steve   Apples
1  November    Joe  Oranges
2  December  James   Apples
2  December  James  Oranges
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! explode looks like exactly what I was looking for. I am currently trying to make this work in my code and will mark as answered once I figure out exactly how this works.